# Decrypting SSH packets with Wireshark

Tags: ssh, wireshark, opendaylight, ietf-netconf

I'd like to decrypt Wireshark-captured SSH packets. I have both the public and private keys. How can this be done?

Reason: I am trying to decrypt and check the payload of the Hello exchanged packets between ODL controller and a Netconf Server.

Comment: What you mean by "Hello exchanged packets"? They should not be encrypted. The further ones, that are encrypted, you can't. If you could, the protocol would not be secure. They are encrypted using one-time secret derived from the result of key exchange.

Comment: @Jakuje With the private key, can't he determine the key exchange secret?

Comment: @JeremyBanks No. Diffie-Hellman key exchange is using the private key, but also random data from both sides, therefore anyone "on the wire" can't derive the shared secret. This is the main point of DH key exchange.

Comment: but wouldn't that random data be included in the Wireshark dump in a form that he could extract? I don't understand how this would be impossible; it seems like he could essentially replay the exchange as the client and obtain the same state. (Don't feel obligated to humor my ignorant questions.)

Comment: @Jakuje, the OP may be referring to NETCONF <hello> messages. This protocol uses SSH as transport and has its own hello exchange which would be encrypted entirely (it happens after an SSH session has been established).

Comment: If you wish to debug NETCONF messages, the best way would be to check logs on both sides of the connection.

Comment: The Hello messages are also encrypted and yes you are right, it cant be decrypted. I got to know this from other sources too. It seems i will have to struggle on log to find out this.

Comment: Is there any way by which i can make the connection only on TCP not including ssh?